# Printing json element causes TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json

I have this requests code:

```
url = endpoint + 'listSites.adm'
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(admin, password), verify=False)
data = res.json()
print data['responseData']['sites']['name']


{u'sites': [{u'name': u'My Site', u'timestamp': 1541514223000, u'company': None, u'description': None, u'longitude': None, u'country': None, u'abbreviation': None, u'phone': None, u'ldapServiceName': None, u'address': None, u'latitude': None, u'creationDate': u'Tue, 06 Nov 2018 14:23:43 +0000', u'id': 1, u'uuid': u'bb1b7df3-af55-77a4-1047-489d0eb3f346'}]}
```

I want to print the name but it returns this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using Python3 but have limited experience so may be using Python2 code.

If I add `print(data)` I get the json string shown in my question. I want to go a step further and only print the value in `name`(i.e. `My Site`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to get it working:

data['responseData']['sites'][0]['name']

Sites is an array so must be indexed.

Comment: Please say that this is what worked and how it did, also accept as your answer, even though it's from you. There is a badge for that (just fyi)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a json back it will usually be a list of dictionaries, thus the following should work.

```
data[0]['responseData']['sites']['name']
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That didn't work for me. I ended up doing something similar though. `data['responseData']['sites'][0]['name']`

Comment: I've totally misread the last line of your question, glad you've found the answer